# A better name for the „teachers” tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a [teachers](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teachers) tag for questions about educating teachers, whose name is far from useful, in my opinion. Though it only has a few questions right now, there will inevitably more questions about this.

Does anybody have a good suggestion for a tag for such questions?

Comment: I created a tag [tag:teacher-training] following this discussion.  (Yet, it does not fit for all instances of the old tag I think.)

Comment: I've noticed "teachers" has been used a couple of times in the last week, and it is not always in the context of "teacher-training", but it is also not really used in a meaningful way on its own. I think some current posts should have "teachers" removed, and the rest have it changed to "teacher-training".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In British English [teacher-training](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teacher-training) would be more natural. I don't know if that sounds right in American.

Comment: To my (American) ear it sounds fine.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [teacher-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teacher-education)?